# Continuity of a function in its domain or out side domain

Tags: calculus, continuity

Which of the following functions is/are continuous?

(A) $\frac{1}{x-1}$

(B) $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$

(C) $sign(x-2)$

(D) $sin(x)$

My answer is $A,B,D.$
But answer given is D only ?

Comment: Hint: Is A, B are defined for all x?

Comment: Check your textbook: when it says a function is continuous, does that mean it's continuous everywhere it's defined, or continuous for all real numbers $x$? (Both conventions are used; I suspect your conception differs from your book's convention.)

Comment: A and B are not defined at x=1

Comment: @Greg Martin: How can we define continuity outside domain !!

Comment: First check if the functions are continuous or not ex: sign(x-2) =$\frac{x-2}{|x-2|}$ is not continuous at x=2 as as the left limit (at x->$2^-$) doesn't equal the right limit at (x->$2^+$).